# Open corresponding app on Handheld without notification from Android Wearable (Gear live)

Tags: android, wear-os, handheld

I would like to develop an app on the wearable wich should be able to launch an app on my Handheld device, without the notification standard ("open on device") action.
It should start the app on the handheld, even if the Handheld App is closed at the moment. Is there a solution to achieve this. I can't find it in the documentation.
If I overread that in the official doc., please post a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you have to use the [Wearable Data Layer API](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html).

Just send a message using the [Message API](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html) from the Android Wear device to the handheld's one. The [WearableListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) of your handheld app can then launch an `Intent` to open the app.