# Android - Launch an App on Phone From Watch

Tags: android

Before the question, I am truly sorry if there was a question like this, but I googled it and couldn't find any topic.

I am trying to launch an app on the phone by a request that comes from a wearable. Is there any way to send such a request directly from an app which is running on the wearable?

Edit: I am curious that if there is a way to do this WITHOUT using Message API (sending a message to phone so that phone launces an intent to run the app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open corresponding app on Handheld without notification from Android Wearable (Gear live)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189341/open-corresponding-app-on-handheld-without-notification-from-android-wearable-g)

Comment: Wow, could't find this. Thank you and again very sorry for the duplicate. Though i am curious that if there is a way to do this WITHOUT using Message API